# How do I restart the 2.2 update for HTC Desire?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates

I just got the notification for the 2.2 update for my HTC Desire (on O2 in the UK).  I downloaded and let the update install.  After a couple of reboots it told me it couldn't install as I needed to clean up some memory, which I've now done.

How do I restart the update install?  I've tried restarting the phone and going to the phone settings and checking for updates, but it doesn't find any updates and it's still reporting 2.1 installed.

---

Update:
Turns out the update file was on my SD card, but renaming it to update.zip and following Al. E's steps didn't work - I get a file not signed errors ("failed to verify whole-file signature" and "signature verification failed".

I've also since done a hard reset too, and now have open call with HTC second line support. Will update you when they get back to me.

Apparently setting the date to the future would cause the OTA to be detected again, but my date won't stay set to the future (yes, I have turned off network date updates!). I'm now researching how to use a file manager to update from the 2.2 zip file.

Watch this space...

---

Update 2: Okay, I finally cracked it!  First, I downloaded the UK O2 update from HTC's site, then followed Al E's method below to install the update.  Job done!!

The URL for the download was http://liveimage.htc.com/.  I knew the name of the update file as it was in my sd\download folder.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm interested in the ultimate solution.

Comment: No worries :) - I'll get back when I know more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>`Settings | About phone | System updates`</s>

It should let you know that there's an update available.

If you still have the update.zip file on your SD card, these instructions should do it: http://geekword.net/manually-install-froyo-htc-desire

> Step 1: Download the Android 2.2
>   firmware for the Desire from [here](http://hotfile.com/dl/58947725/9565587/OTA_Bravo_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.09.405.8-1.21.405.2_release4dua3bcrut4wrv30.zip.html).
>
> Step 2: Rename the file update.zip and
>   copy it to your microSD card via USB.
>   [Note: make sure the file is named
>   update.zip and not update.zip.zip.]
>
> Step 3: Power down your Desire.
>
> Step 4: Hold down the “Volume Down” button
>   as you power the phone back on.
>
> Step 5: A screen should appear showing your
>   phone’s system searching for various
>   files. Scroll down to “recovery” and
>   press the “Power” button.
>
> Step 6: When you see the triangle with an
>   exclamation point symbol, press the
>   “Power” and “Volume Up” buttons at the
>   same time.
>
> Step 7: From the menu that appears, select “Apply
>   sdcard:update.zip.”
>
> Step 8: When the screen displays “Install from sdcard
>   complete” select “reboot system now”
>   and wait for the phone to power back
>   up.

Comment: @Al E - nope, tried that and it says I'm up to date!

Comment: Pop the battery out?

Comment: Nope - still won't find the update online. As I downloaded it before, can run it from the phone somehow?

Comment: Perhaps. If you still have the update.zip file on your SD card, these instructions should do it: http://www.geekword.net/manually-install-froyo-htc-desire/

Comment: Al, that's a great help as I now know the name of the update file. However, unfortunately there's no update* file on my phone :(  Guess I'll have to wait until the update gets picked up again then?!?!

Comment: I edited my answer with the full instructions. You can get the update.zip file by following Step 1. (FWIW, I manually updated my Motorola Droid to the initial Froyo release using similar instructions, and it worked fine.)

Comment: As a last resort, you could always do a factory reset.

Comment: Did it work? Don't leave us hanging...

Comment: Hi Al, no file at the link you posted, just: "This file is either removed due to copyright claim or is deleted by the uploader".

Comment: Since the OTA update is available there's probably less of a drive to have the manual update file available, but it's probably still out there somewhere. I think you should consider a factory reset.